# One URL for Images & HTML

Tags: html, http

Is it possible to have one URL where if it's in an image tag it will display the images, but if it's loaded in the browser it'll display an HTML page?

Comment: Not too clear on what you mean here. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @hellsgate well I want to provide one url to users that would dynamically display either image or html, depending on how it's requested. Like, how can I detect that?

Comment: @joseph What would be the possible different request methods? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @hellsgate Either in an img tag or in the browser.

Comment: @Joseph could you tell us why you want to do that? Maybe there's another solution to your problem.

Comment: I'm giving the users a URL based on their input. By default I want it to render as an image, because that's usually where it'll go. At the same time, I also want to give them the option to send that URL to someone. When that "someone" clicks on it, I would want to display more than just the image. So I wanted something instead of giving the user 2 urls.

Comment: @Joseph Ah, some sites like Photobucket do this by giving "sharing codes" for putting them in sites, forums, etc. that contain both the image and a link. Of course some users strip the link and just hotlink to the actual image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the HTTP requests are the same for either an `img` tag or for loading them in the browser.

You can however force a download if not in an image tag with the http header `Content-Disposition: attachment` or by associating an unknown mime-type such as `Content-Type: application/foo`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That's what Content Negotiation is for, after all.

Of course, those two Representations must represent the same Resource.

Comment: So how would one go about that. How can I tell what's being requested?

Comment: With Content Negotiation. That's what it was invented for, after all: to be able to have multiple Representations of the same Resource and have the Client and the Server negotiate the best possible Representation.

Comment: Got you. Is it supported cross-browser?

Comment: But browsers don't send these things unless the user specifies them, right? because I've never seen quality scales for image resources and so on in any header I've seen. Furthermore, it doesn't tell the server if it was loaded inline or if the user has gone directly to the image as per the questioner's request.

Comment: @Joseph: Given that it would be pretty much impossible to display *anything* without at least a minimum support for Content Negotiation, I'm pretty sure it has been supported for 15 years now. For non-browsers, however, the situation is much different. REST and AtomPub don't work without CN, so such clients should be safe, but feedreaders are very spotty. I read that there is a very popular feedreader that *always* requests a `text/html` Representation, but can actually only deal with `application/xml+atom` and `application/rss`, and thus simply shows a blank page.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag Just did a quick check with Fiddler. It appears that the exact same request headers were sent to both types of requests (using Chrome)

Comment: @Jörg the questioner is asking about browsers I think, but furthermore, on Webkit and Gecko AFAIK I can load an image even if the server sends the wrong mime-type as long as it's in an `img` tag.

Comment: +1 this is the only way to achieve what the poster asks, but it's not at all advisable. There are many problems with using the Accept header in practice including inconsistent browser behaviour in both top-context and img-context, and the need to use `Vary` (to prevent proxies caching the wrong version), resulting in other caching problems in IE. Give up and use marginally-different URLs.

Comment: Bobince is correct. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/06/17/vary-header-prevents-caching-in-ie.aspx for discussion.